# Angular 5 HttpClient returning undefined to a subscribed function and cannot change a variable

Tags: angular, http, httpclient, angular5

I need to display a message to user so he can know that his email already exist in our database. I have this mehtod:

```
addPartners(partnerName, showMsg)
{
    showMsg = false;
    const headerOptions = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    const body = new HttpParams().set('name', partnerName);
    return this.http.post('http://aff.local/addPartner.php', body, {
          headers: headerOptions
}).pipe(map(
    res=>{

      //console.log(res)
      if(res==null)
      {
        //alert("Your email already exist in our database");
        showMsg = true;
      }
      else{
        showMsg=false;
      }
    },
    error=>{
      console.log("Error: "+ error);
    }
  ))
 }
```

And I run it in my component on click:

```
addPartner(){
    this.email = this.subscribeForm.get('emailTxt').value;
    console.log("hi "+this.email);
    this.api.addPartners(this.email, this.showMsg).subscribe(
      (data)=>{
        console.log(this.showMsg);

        this.subscribeForm.reset();
      },
      (error)=>{
        console.log(error)
      }
    );
  }
```

In the DOM when `showMsg` is true, I will display the message:

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="showMsg">
   ...
</div>
```

My problem is that I always get at the console of `console.log(this.showMsg)` an `undefined` as returned value. That's why `showMsg` is always false even if the email already exists and I should display a message to user.

I tried to see the `data` value at the console:

`console.log(data);`

And I still get `undefined` at the console.

What I want exactly, is to change the value to true, when I already have the email in my database. Here is my php script to understand more:

```
public function addPartner($partner_name){
        global $conn;
        //$existingValueMsg = "Email already exists";
        $existingValue = "SELECT * FROM partner WHERE partner_name=:partner_name";
        $execExistingValue=$conn->prepare($existingValue);
        $execExistingValue->bindValue(":partner_name", $partner_name);
        $execExistingValue->execute();
        $execExistingValue->fetchAll();
        $resultNumber = $execExistingValue->rowCount();
        if($resultNumber==0)
        {
            $addParner = "INSERT INTO partner(partner_name, image) VALUES(:partner_name, '')";
            $execAddPartner = $conn->prepare($addParner);
            $execAddPartner->bindValue(":partner_name", $partner_name);
            $execAddPartner->execute();

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //return $existingValueMsg;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

When false, at the typescript method the returned value is `null`.

Comment: your map operation in the addPartners method has no return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass in `showMsg` to your service. `showMsg` value will not be updated in your service because javascript is pass by value, as mentioned by @JB Nizet.

Therefore, what you should do is return boolean result in your service, subscribe it in your component, then assign it to `showMsg` - `this.showMsg = data`.

Demo Code can be found here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhyab1.
Refer to `app component` and `partner service`.

Comment: Can you explain here the difference between `map()` and `switchMap()` and `of()`

Comment: `of()` here is in the place of return ?

Comment: for `of()`, you must return an observable inside `switchMap()`. Therefore, you need to convert the boolean to observable. In order to do that, we use `of()` - to convert something to observable.

Comment: for difference btw `map()` and `switchMap()` - actually your code can use map. Let me edit the solution.

Comment: edited, check `addPartnersMap`. Basically `map` return value directly in your case, while `switchMap` return observable of value. Sorry for confusing you with `switchMap`.

Comment: Please use `map` operator.

Comment: Thanks Sir. Your explanation was great

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is pass by value.

```
function increment(i: number) {
  i++;
}

let i  = 0; 
increment(i); 
console.log(i);`
```

This will **always** print 0. Because a *copy* of `i` is passed to `increment()`.

Use the `map()` rxjs operator to transform the emitted event into true or false. Then, shen you subscribe from your component, the event you receive will be true or false, and you can act accordingly.

Comment: I am already using `pipe(map(...))` and can't know how to fix it.

Comment: map() must **return** the result of the transformation, i.e. true or false.